# java connection to jabber

Tags: java, sockets, stream, xmpp

What type of stream I need to use to write  a connect request message over a tcp socket, to jabber.
I'mwriting a string with xml format. It should worked with the default socket stream or a dataoutputstream but it doesn't.

Comment: explain the "but it doesn't" part and you will get more meaningful answers

Answer (score 4):

Use the [Smack](http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/smack/index.jsp) client library to connect to a Jabber server, such as OpenFire.  It is quite simple to use, you can connect and send/receive messages in a few lines of code.

Comment: +1 on Smack. Easy-to-use, simple, feature-rich, works well. Very happy with it.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to try Openfire (formerly Wildfire). It uses the only widely adopted open protocol for instant messaging, XMPP (also called Jabber).

Take a look [here](http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/openfire/index.jsp) or for the source [here](http://www.igniterealtime.org/downloads/source.jsp)

Answer (score 0):

Jabber is a pretty comprehensive protocol, so I don't think it's really analogous to opening a stream.  On the other hand, it's a very well supported protocol, so you have your choice of libraries to help.  Here is a link to the relevant information on [jabber.org](http://www.jabber.org/web/Libraries#Java).